# Image produced is incomplete - Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with bytes

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to load a tflite model and run it on an image.

My tflite model has the dimensions you see in the image.
[image: tflite]

Right now, I am receiving:

`Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with 49152 bytes from a Java Buffer with 175584 bytes.`

I can't understand how to work with input and output tensor sizes. Right now, I am initializing using the input image size and the output image size will be `input * 4`.

At which point do I have to "add" the `1 * 64 * 64 * 3` dimensions since I need to manipulate every input image size?

```
 try {
                    tflitemodel = loadModelFile()
                    tflite = Interpreter(tflitemodel, options)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fail to load model", e)
                }

                val imageTensorIndex = 0
                val imageShape: IntArray =
                    tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape()
                val imageDataType: DataType = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType()
                // Build a TensorImage object
                var inputImageBuffer = TensorImage(imageDataType);

                // Load the Bitmap
                inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap)

                // Preprocess image
                val imgprocessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
                    .add(ResizeOp(inputImageBuffer.height,
                        inputImageBuffer.width,
                        ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
                    //.add(NormalizeOp(127.5f, 127.5f))
                    //.add(QuantizeOp(128.0f, 1 / 128.0f))
                    .build()

                // Process the image
                val processedImage = imgprocessor.process(inputImageBuffer)

                // Access the buffer ( byte[] ) of the processedImage
                val imageBuffer = processedImage.buffer
                val imageTensorBuffer = processedImage.tensorBuffer

                // output result
                val outputImageBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(
                    intArrayOf( inputImageBuffer.height * 4 ,
                        inputImageBuffer.width * 4 ) ,
                    DataType.FLOAT32 )

                // Normalize image
                val tensorProcessor = TensorProcessor.Builder()
                    // Normalize the tensor given the mean and the standard deviation
                    .add( NormalizeOp( 127.5f, 127.5f ) )
                    .add( CastOp( DataType.FLOAT32 ) )
                    .build()
                val processedOutputTensor = tensorProcessor.process(outputImageBuffer)


                tflite.run(imageTensorBuffer.buffer, processedOutputTensor.buffer)
```

I tried to cast the output tensor either to FLOAT32 or UINT8.

**UPDATE**

I also tried this :

```
 try {
         tflitemodel = loadModelFile()
         tflite = Interpreter(tflitemodel, options)
      } catch (e: IOException) {

          Log.e(TAG, "Fail to load model", e)
        }

 val imageTensorIndex = 0
 val imageDataType: DataType = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType()

 val imgprocessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
                    .add(ResizeOp(64,
                                 64,
                        ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
                        )
                    .add( NormalizeOp( 0.0f, 255.0f ) )
                    .add( CastOp( DataType.FLOAT32 ) )
                    .build()

 val inpIm = TensorImage(imageDataType)
 inpIm.load(bitmap)

 val processedImage = imgprocessor.process(inpIm)

 val output = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(
                        intArrayOf(
                            124 * 4,
                            118 * 4,
                            3,
                            1
                        ),
                        DataType.FLOAT32
                    )

 val tensorProcessor = TensorProcessor.Builder()
                        
                        .add( NormalizeOp( 0.0f, 255.0f ) )
                        .add( CastOp( DataType.FLOAT32 ) )
                        .build()

 val processedOutputTensor = tensorProcessor.process(output)


 tflite.run(processedImage.buffer, processedOutputTensor.buffer)
```

which produces:

[image: this image]

Note, that the current image I am using as input has `124 * 118 * 3` dimensions.

The output image will have `(124 * 4) * (118 * 4) * 3` dimensions.

The model needs `64 * 64 * 3` as input layer.

Comment: Hi George. Is there a working python example to see how the image is processed and how the inference is working? There are a lot of things that are happening and the error could be at a lot of places. The error clearly displays that you are feeding the model with different size of bytes than what it is expecting.

Comment: @Farmaker: Hello! I uploaded 2 files, thanks. https://files.fm/u/7pr3usazw

Comment: @Farmaker: and the tflite file. https://files.fm/f/rz2buh3ca

Comment: Ok give me some time to take a look at them.

Comment: I tried to test it on Colab with version of TensorFlow 2.8.0 and it gives :
ValueError: Model provided has model identifier 'rt t', should be 'TFL3'.
It seems that it is malformed? What is your TensorFlow version? Does it work with the python script?

Comment: Also from the code I see that you resize tensor input:
`interpreter.resize_tensor_input(0, [1, height, width, channels])` which I do not see at the Kotlin code above and is sure an issue for the Exception you get Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with 49152 bytes from a Java Buffer with 175584 bytes.

Comment: Also you are doing at the output:
sr = tf.clip_by_value(sr, 0, 255)
sr = tf.round(sr)
sr = tf.cast(sr, tf.uint8)

img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(sr)

which I also do not see at the second block of code. I believe you have to do all the operations one by one before you create your final Bitmap.

Comment: But first things first...I can not load the .tflite file

Comment: @Farmaker: The tflite file seems ok. I am using tensorfloe version `2.4.1`. The resizing takes place at `imgprocessor builder`.I believe that the `clip_values` is the same as the normalization 0-255 that takes place in the `tensorProcessor`.I am not sure about the cast to uint8 since I see that if I do that in the `tensorProcessor`, I am getting the `Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with 786432 bytes ...`.  I am refering to the second part of the code, the `UPDATED` one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242970/discussion-between-farmaker-and-george).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your project, your class will be like:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val TAG = "SuperResolution"
    private val MODEL_NAME = "model_edsr.tflite"
    private val LR_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 24
    private val LR_IMAGE_WIDTH = 24
    private val UPSCALE_FACTOR = 4
    private val SR_IMAGE_HEIGHT = LR_IMAGE_HEIGHT * UPSCALE_FACTOR
    private val SR_IMAGE_WIDTH = LR_IMAGE_WIDTH * UPSCALE_FACTOR

    private lateinit var photoButton: Button
    private lateinit var srButton: Button
    private lateinit var colorizeButton: Button
    private var FILE_NAME = "photo.jpg"

    private lateinit var filename:String
    private var resultImg: Bitmap? = null

    private lateinit var gpuSwitch: Switch

    private lateinit var tflite: Interpreter
    private lateinit var tflitemodel: ByteBuffer

    private val INPUT_SIZE: Int = 96
    private val PIXEL_SIZE: Int = 3
    private val IMAGE_MEAN = 0
    private val IMAGE_STD = 255.0f


    private var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var bitmapResult: Bitmap? = null

    /** A ByteBuffer to hold image data, to be feed into Tensorflow Lite as input/output  */
    private lateinit var imgDataInput: ByteBuffer
    private lateinit var imgDataOutput: ByteBuffer

    /** Dimensions of inputs.  */
    private val DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 1

    private val DIM_PIXEL_SIZE = 3

    private val DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 64
    private val DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 64
    private lateinit var catBitmap: Bitmap
    /* Preallocated buffers for storing image data in. */
    private val intValues = IntArray(DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y)
    private lateinit var superImage: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        superImage = findViewById(R.id.super_resolution_image)

        //val assetManager = assets
        catBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset("cat.png")


        srButton = findViewById(R.id.super_resolution)
        srButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->

            val intent = Intent(this, SelectedImage::class.java)
            getImageResult.launch(intent)
        }


    }

    private fun getBitmapFromAsset(filePath: String?): Bitmap {
        val assetManager = assets
        val istr: InputStream
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(filePath!!)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // handle exception
            Log.e("Bitmap_except", e.toString())

        }

        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,64,64,true)
        }

        return bitmap?: Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    }

    private val getImageResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                var theImageUri: Uri? = null
                theImageUri = result.data?.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("imageuri")

                filename = "SR_" + theImageUri?.getOriginalFileName(this).toString()

                bitmap = uriToBitmap(theImageUri!!)!!//catBitmap//
                Log.v("width", bitmap!!.width.toString())

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    // call DL
                    val options = Interpreter.Options()
                    options.setNumThreads(5)
                    options.setUseNNAPI(true)
                    try {
                        tflitemodel = loadModelFile()
                        tflite = Interpreter(tflitemodel, options)
                        val index = tflite.getInputIndex("input_1")
                        tflite.resizeInput(
                            index,
                            intArrayOf(1, bitmap!!.width, bitmap!!.height, 3)
                        )
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Fail to load model", e)
                    }

                    val imgprocessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
                        .add(
                           ResizeOp(bitmap!!.width,
                                bitmap!!.height,
                                ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
                        )
                        .add( CastOp( DataType.FLOAT32 ) )
                        .build()

                    val inpIm = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
                    inpIm.load(bitmap)

                    // Process the image
                    val processedImage = imgprocessor.process(inpIm)

                    val output2 = Array(1) { Array(4*bitmap!!.width) { Array(4*bitmap!!.height) { FloatArray(3) } } }

                    tflite.run(processedImage.buffer, output2)

                    bitmapResult = convertArrayToBitmap(output2, 4*bitmap!!.height, 4*bitmap!!.width)

                    Log.v("widthHR", bitmapResult!!.height.toString())
                    superImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult)

                }
            }
        }


    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun loadModelFile(): MappedByteBuffer {
        val fileDescriptor = assets.openFd(MODEL_NAME)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
        val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
        val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
    }


    private fun uriToBitmap(selectedFileUri: Uri): Bitmap? {
        try {
            val parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(selectedFileUri, "r")
            val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor!!.fileDescriptor
            val image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
            parcelFileDescriptor.close()
            return image
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun getOutputImage(output: ByteBuffer): Bitmap? {
        output.rewind()
        val outputWidth = 124 * 4
        val outputHeight = 118 * 4
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputWidth, outputHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val pixels = IntArray(outputWidth * outputHeight)
        for (i in 0 until outputWidth * outputHeight) {
            val a = 0xFF
            val r = output.float * 255.0f
            val g = output.float * 255.0f
            val b = output.float * 255.0f
            pixels[i] = a shl 24 or (r.toInt() shl 16) or (g.toInt() shl 8) or b.toInt()
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, outputWidth, 0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight)
        return bitmap
    }

    // save bitmap image to gallery
    private fun saveToGallery(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, albumName: String) {
        //val filename = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
        val write: (OutputStream) -> Boolean = {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it)
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM}/$albumName")
            }

            context.contentResolver.let {
                it.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)?.let { uri ->
                    it.openOutputStream(uri)?.let(write)
                }
            }
        } else {
            val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + albumName
            val file = File(imagesDir)
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir()
            }
            val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
            write(FileOutputStream(image))
        }
    }

    // get the filename from an image uri
    private fun Uri.getOriginalFileName(context: Context): String? {
        return context.contentResolver.query(this,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null)?.use {
            val nameColumnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            it.moveToFirst()
            it.getString(nameColumnIndex)
        }
    }
    fun convertArrayToBitmap(
        imageArray: Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>>,
        imageWidth: Int,
        imageHeight: Int
    ): Bitmap {

        val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // see other conf types
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, conf)

        for (x in imageArray[0].indices) {
            for (y in imageArray[0][0].indices) {
                // Create bitmap to show on screen after inference
                val color = Color.rgb(
                    (imageArray[0][x][y][0]).toInt(),
                    (imageArray[0][x][y][1]).toInt(),
                    (imageArray[0][x][y][2]).toInt()
                )

                // this y, x is in the correct order!!!
                bitmap.setPixel(y, x, color)
            }
        }
        return bitmap
    }

}
```

take a look inside how we resize the inputs of the model inside android, how we create input buffer and output array and how we convert the produced array to a Bitmap. For these procedures check if you can use Gpu of the phone to have x3 speed and of course there are plenty to read at the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide).